AWS CDK Lambda Deployment to existing API gateway (no existing deployment & stage)
I am using AWS CDK to deploy a lambda function with some APIs to an existing API gateway. I am using the CDK to create API resources, methods, stage and deployment. Only the API gateway is precreated .
I have the usual code for CDK Stack. I am able to deploy successfully till creating method without any errors. But If I deploy all including stages and deployment, I am getting "The REST API doesn't contain any methods" deploying the first time. Is this is a known bug or anything to do with race conditions. If I comment out STAGE and DEPLOYMENT part , I can deploy the code without any error but I have to uncomment STAGE and DEPLOYMENT Part and redeploy the code to get the API stages and deployment.
Tech : Nodejs20 , typescript, CDK 2
UPDATE : Error Message
Resource handler returned message: "The REST API doesn't contain any methods (Service: ApiGateway, Status Code:400, Request ID: ........

Code Snippet
export class MyAppStack extends cdk.stack {
 constructor(....)
 ......................
 .........
const lambdafunc = new lambda.Function()
....
....
//creating resource
const userRes = newapi.root.addResource('users');

//creating method
userRes.addMethod('POST',new apigateway.LambdaIntegration(lambdafunc);

//create deployment
newdeployment = new apigateway.Deployment(this, 'NewDeployment', { 
  api : newapi,
  });

//create deployment
  new apigateway.Stage(this, 'devstage', {
     deployment : newdeployment,
     stageName = 'dev',
  });




Please add the error message to the question

Updated error message

Did the answer work?

This is likely occurring because the new stage and deployment you're creating don't depend on the method you've added. You can specify the dependency yourself:
newDeployoment.node.addDependency(userRes);

I am not sure if the stage will use the existing resources, though - test that out.
